# Fubini-Tonelli proof purely using complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $F:[a,b]\times[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that:$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{c}^{d}F(x,y)dy\right)dx = \int_{c}^{d}\left(\int_{a}^{b}F(x,y)dx\right)dy$$

Lebesgue integral hasn't been introduced, and this is from a book concerning complex analysis. Is there a way to show this without the usage of the Lebesgue integral? Using complex analysis? Merci for all hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a version for Riemann-Integrals, too. A quite straight-forward proof can be found in "The College Mathematics Journal" Vol. 33, No. 2 p.126-130, it is available [online](http://www.cmc.edu/math/publications/aksoy/Mixed_Partials.pdf) too.

The main part is a clever application of the mean value theorem. Note also that the term Fubini-Tonelli is mostly used for the Lebesgue-Integral "version" of the theorem.